# Simulate time series from a fitted model

Tags: r, simulation

How to simulate a time series from a fitted model with different length?
Here is the R code that I used.

```
library(forecast)
x <- rnorm(14)
arima_mtd <- auto.arima(x)
simulate(arima_mtd, future=FALSE, obs=20)
```

The output is

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 14 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  2.5615390  2.5141284  4.2861222  3.6109683  3.3430394  1.2106125  0.6632493  0.3742014 -0.9513123 -0.3542338  0.5117973 -0.3833429 -0.2657833 -0.8910624
```

Instead of generating 14 observations I want to generate 20 observations from the fitted model.

Comment: Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, when you have only 14 observations and `future = FALSE` then you can only generate 14 simulated observations. If you require 20 you wither have to generate 6 more observations by setting `future = TRUE`:

```
a = simulate(arima_mtd, future = FALSE, nsim = 14)
b = simulate(arima_mtd, future = TRUE, nsim = 6)
```

Or you will have to increase the number of observations in your initial `x`.

Comment: Thank you. But I am wondering if we simulate 14 and 6 observations above can we guarantee that they come from the same process.

Comment: Instead, we can do it as simulate(arima_mtd, future = TRUE, nsim = 20). Thanks for your answer @AK88

Comment: When you do `simulate(arima_mtd, future = TRUE, nsim = 20)` pay attention to `Start = 15` and `End = 34` - which I think not what you want. You want to simulate 20 current observations not future, right? Given only 14 observations you either have to first simulate observations setting `future = FALSE` and then remaining 6 will be from the future as you have insufficient data. Also, `simulate` generates `one or more responses from the distribution corresponding to a fitted model object`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.